# Why am I getting "Ineligible Submission" when submitting my app to fb app center?

Tags: facebook-app-center

When I submit my application to Facebook app center, I get below error.

```
Ineligible Submission
Your app does not have high enough ratings and user engagement to be eligible for the App    Center at this time.
```

How can I get enough ratings?

Comment: Please start a bounty for this. I am so much in need of this answer